# Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

Right now, I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
```

Now, I want to update Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
I have followed the below steps.

```
sudo apt update
Fetched 70.0 kB in 32s (2,195 B/s)                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
```

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo reboot
```

```
sudo apt --purge autoremoveReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It's started to process to update

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                                                                                  
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,336 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Fetched 1,338 kB in 6s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                          
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done                                                                                              
Fetched 70.0 kB in 6s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

for any reason, it's stopped to upgrade.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: You may need to check the [upgrade policy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#Upgrade_policy). If it is set to 'never', change it to 'lts'.

Comment: @mikewhatever It's already a `Prompt=lts`.